# NgRx Parameterized Selector showing empty result

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx

Trying to utilize a parameterized query in NgRx but getting empty result.

Here's stackblitz version of code below: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngrx-parameterized-query

**Reducer Code**

```
export const userAdapter = createEntityAdapter<UserModel>({
  selectId: x => x.UserId
});
export interface UserlistState extends EntityState<UserModel>{

};

export const initialState: UserlistState = userAdapter.getInitialState({

}); 


export function UserlistReducers(
  state: UserlistState = initialState,
  action: actions.UserlistActions
){
  switch(action.type){

    case actions.UserlistActionTypes.UPSERT_USERS:
      return userAdapter.upsertMany(action.users,state);

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export const getUserlistState = createFeatureSelector<UserlistState>('userlist');

export const {
  selectIds,
  selectEntities,
  selectAll,
  selectTotal
} = userAdapter.getSelectors(getUserlistState);

export const getUsersByOrganizationId = createSelector(selectAll,
    (users: Array<UserModel>, organization_id: number)=>{
        return users.filter(x=> x.OrganizationId == organization_id)
    }
)
```

**Usage**

```
watchlist = ():Observable<UserModel[]> =>{
        return this.userlistStore.select(reducers.selectAll);
    }

    watchlistByOrganizationId = (organization_id: number): Observable<UserModel[]> =>{
        return this.userlistStore.select(reducers.getUsersByOrganizationId(organization_id));
    }
```

Comment: Stackblitz shows an error with your select. It might explain what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is wrong.

This is how it should be; the `organization_id` is the parameter of the selector function, thus it's available in the function scope and there is no need to add it in the arrow functions parameter list. The `selectAll` will return the users and pass it as an argument to the arrow function. The below should work as intended!

```
export const getUsersByOrganizationId = (organization_id: number) => createSelector(selectAll,
  (users: Array<UserModel>) => {
    return users.filter(x => x.OrganizationId == organization_id)
  }
);
```

[StackBlitz without errors.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngrx-parameterized-query-lzxqvx)